# How to make Pydantic's BaseModel accept some special case input types in fastapi app

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, fastapi, pydantic

I have a fastapi app, which takes in "application/json" among other input types and returns "appliction/json". I have a input-validator written sub-classing pydantic's `BaseModel` and I would like to make it accept some cases of inputs which I do receive and not generate `fastapi.exceptions.RequestValidationError` on them.

some accepted inputs (`List[List[float]]`):

1. `{"input_json":[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]]}`
2. `{"input_json":[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0]]}`

I would like to make it accept following input cases:

1. `{"input_json":[[1.0, 2.0, .0, 4.]]}` (no number after decimal point, numpy arrays and python lists accept such inputs by populating 0 after period, but pydantic throws validation error.)
2. `{"input_json":[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]}` (no list of lists, but just a list. i will handle the shape internally doing `numpy.my_array.reshape(-1, 4)`, but I want pydantic to not generate `RequestValidationError` and send the input to my fastapi endpoints.)
3. `{"input_json":[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0],]}` (comma at the end of second nested list. both numpy and python lists accept such inputs, but pydantic doesn't.)

Here's how my validaiton class is written:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class InputResponse(BaseModel):
    input_json: List[List[float]]

    @validator("input_json")
    def check_dimensionality(cls, list_of_lists):
        for nested_list in list_of_lists:
            if len(nested_list) != 4:
                raise ValueError(incomplete_msg)
        return list_of_lists
```

what changes do I make to be able to accept all of those input cases?

Comment: 3 is invalid JSON. it should not exist.

Comment: oh, i didn't know that. thanks for the input @LotB.

Answer (score 1):

For that, you can either define a `TypeVar` or use a union type. In code that looks like

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Union
T = TypeVar("T", list[list[float]], list[float])

# Option with TypeVar
class InputResponse(BaseModel):
    input_json: T

# Option with Union type
class InputResponse(BaseModel):
    input_json: Union[list[list[float]], list[float]]
```

Regarding the missing zero after the decimal point, I haven't seen an issue with that.

Comment: thanks for your time and the answer. i did get request validation errors with missing numbers after decimals point. and is there a way to deal with comma at the end.